# Regex with negative lookahead matches more than needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't get my regex working...

These are my test case

```
/templates/blue-business-bi-fold-brochure-4eef5269-0957-4f14-ad6c-1343a2fe75a3
/templates/flyers/4eef5269-0957-4f14-ad6c-1343a2fe75a3
/templates/brochures/theatre-playbill-program
/templates/infographics/diversity-and-inclusion-terminology-infographic-dbc47165-dee4-478f-a0b9-313a54a5338a
```

I want to target the 3rd case, and only the 3rd `/templates/brochures/theatre-playbill-program` (note that it doesn't have a UUID)

https://regex101.com/r/EXtNBP/1

What am I doing wrong? I know the issue is with the second group greedy, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Problem with your attempt is that it requires last group not to be followed by uuid and simultaneously be immediately followed by end of line. Please notice that lookaraounds are non capturing!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, seems I needed to group the negative lookahead with the other condition

```
^\/(templates\/)([0-9a-z-]+\/)([a-z-]+(?!([a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12})))$
```

Comment: If you just want to test if the string does not end in a UUID, a negative lookbehind anchored to the end of the line would suffice: `(?<!\b\w{4}(?:\w{4}-){4}\w{12})$`.